# jQuery = Focus com this

Tags: jquery

Em:

```
var form = $('body div#contato section.contato');

if ($(form).find('#nome').val()=='') {
  alert ('Preencha nome');
  $(this).focus();
  return false;
};
```

Qual é a forma correta de se chamar o `this`?

ele emite o `alert` mas não faz o focus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vc fizer só isso

```
    var form = $('body div#contato section.contato');

    if ($(form).find('#nome').val() == '') {
        console.log(this);
    };
```

Vc vai ver que o que o console retorna é

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja retorna a própria janela do browser, pois o `this` não é o `form` nem o `#nome`. Se vc quer que o focus vá para o `#nome` coloque como abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var form = $('body div#contato section.contato');

if ($(form).find('#nome').val() == '') {
    alert('Preencha nome');
    $('#nome').focus();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="contato">
    <section class="contato">
        <input tipe="text" id="nome">
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu havia entendido que, se eu estou dentro de um if, o elemento do if seria o this. Mas faz sentido não ser pois é apenas uma condição e NÃO estamos modificando o elemento! Entendi. Obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha sim o if, é uma função booleana, normalmente é Treu, mas pode ser False,  de qq forma, o this não poderia ser o form ou no #nome, então retorna a própria janela, mesmo estando dentro da condição

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @CarlosRocha sem problemas jovem! Sempre que tiver dúvidas dessas coisas coloca um console.log(this) para ver o que está retornando, isso ajuda a entender as coisas, sempre que vc for construir uma função vai dando uns console.log para ir acompanhando as coisas. abs